# Array Initialization In Uppaal

Tags: arrays, initialization, modeling, uppaal

I have the following struct:

```
const int MAX = 6;
typedef struct {
    int num1;
    int arr1[MAX]; 
    int arr2[MAX];
    int num2;
} MyStruct;
```

And I initialize this array likes the following:

```
MyStruct myStruct = {1, {-1}, {2,-1}, 1};
```

But get the following errors, for the first element:

> Invalid Initialiser

And for the second element:

> too many elements in initialiser

I should have mentioned that the Uppaal version that I use is `4.1.19`. 
So, the question is where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Uppaal documentation, some basic syntaxes are inherited from C++, including array initialization. However, there is a difference that is not bold anywhere. Suppose, we have the following array initialization in C++:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3}; // arr has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
```

In the opposite side, if we write the same statement in Uppaal, we will get `wrong number of elements in array initialiser` error, and we need to initialize an array completely likes the below:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,0,0};
```

It means you need to initialize the array with its size (not lesser).